# Asp.net Get User IP address

Tags: asp.net, ip

```
var result = GetUser_IP();

  protected string GetUser_IP()
        {
            string ipList = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipList))
            {
                return ipList.Split(',')[0];
            }

            return Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
```

result always displays  **::1** why can I not see IP address instead of **::1**

Also what is **::1** for a IP address result ?

What I miss in code, how can I get my IP address like in http://whatismyipaddress.com/ ?

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `::1` is a IP Address of localhost. When ever you will run your application using visual studio it will provide you a IP address is of localhost.

`::1` is the loopback address in IPv6. Think of it as the IPv6 version of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I want some users to access of management page in my code in local . How can i do this ? I do not want everyone to access to page

Comment: Use username and password.

Comment: @Soner — The way you are doing already. You just need to have your network configured so the traffic comes from the IP address you care about. (This is **not** something you should worry about when accessing via localhost).

Comment: When i publish my project and load to server you mean it will be worked.. If it is I will do this way i am trusting you :)

Answer (score 0):

use below method

```
public static string GetVisitorIPAddress(HttpContext _context)
{
    bool GetLan = true;
    string visitorIPAddress = _context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorIPAddress))
        visitorIPAddress = _context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorIPAddress))
        visitorIPAddress = _context.Request.UserHostAddress;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorIPAddress) || visitorIPAddress.Trim() == "::1")
    {
        GetLan = true;
        visitorIPAddress = string.Empty;
    }

    if (GetLan)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorIPAddress))
        {
            //This is for Local(LAN) Connected ID Address
            string stringHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            //Get Ip Host Entry
            IPHostEntry ipHostEntries = Dns.GetHostEntry(stringHostName);
            //Get Ip Address From The Ip Host Entry Address List
            System.Net.IPAddress[] arrIpAddress = ipHostEntries.AddressList;

            try
            {
                visitorIPAddress = arrIpAddress[arrIpAddress.Length - 0].ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                try
                {
                    visitorIPAddress = arrIpAddress[0].ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                    try
                    {
                        arrIpAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(stringHostName);
                        visitorIPAddress = arrIpAddress[0].ToString();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        visitorIPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return visitorIPAddress;
}
```